# Alternatives to 'perspectives'

Tags: layout, personalisation

When looking at popular software like Eclipse, Adobe, 3D-Sutdio-Max, XCode they all do all the same to narrow the interface to a specific task by re-organizing the layout & panels for you. This works fine and as best you can extend or adjust this 'perspectives' further.

The question: are there more possibilities to that 'perspective' quick switches(usually done via combobox or toolbar buttons but I am not just asking for another type to display the access to different 'perspectives' but rather about other 'ideas' or concepts to enable the user quick access to his own customized layout)?

I couldn't find anything via Google nor I could come up with something else or even better; so here I am, asking the experts. Possibly there are new ux approaches to deal with this problem.
thanks

Comment: +1 on the nice question this is a similar thought I have had for a while when using tools like you described

Comment: Did you do the crowd sourced perspective that I mentioned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The creator of the IDE or tool could collect data from users with common workflows and try generalize that perspective for a "suggested perspective"**

Here is one way they could do it and sort of predict what a users perspective might be. Lets say you work on a variety of projects in eclipse.

Lets say right now your working on a JAVA Spring application sticking to server side code. They could see how other users primarily arrange their windows and tabs and maybe they notice 80% of users have the console window at the bottom and 75% of users have the source tree at the right and 56% of users have a unit testing tab open behind the source tree. They might detect that the files you have open fit this common workflow and ask you if you want to try the "suggested perspective".

Like wise if someone was doing an angularJS application in eclipse and they were just sticking to front end code, maybe they could collect some data on common windows that are open and the arrangment and then make a suggested layout.

How this alters is that it is dynamic in it pulls data from how the users set up their workflows, rather than just giving you a precanned J2EE enviroment perspective that doesnt change once that version is released. IE a web development perspective may be great until say the MEAN stack caught on and rather than wait for a new release of your IDE it could **possibly detect how users are laying out their windows and tabs for a dynamic crowd sourced perspective**.

Comment: So that's close to something like 'Save as Perspective', just that we have an automatic-mode which collects all data. +20 for the nice answer, thank you!

Comment: hi, I could manage to implement something like this, and it worked; My Users are fine with the outcome.